# Wanting opinion on implementation of asyncio primitives on complex project structure with asyncio.Queue

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am currently working on a specific area of a large asynchronous Python project, and I was wanting some opinions on how I could implement some sort of `await queue.is_no_longer_full()` functionality to my program without some absurd bootlegging. I figured that using asyncio's primitives might be my best option, but frankly, I am new to the concepts and not well versed enough to rationalize this specific problem.

I dumbed down the problem for the sake of example but the reality is that while the project has a similar style to this, it is much more complex -- please disregard the simplicity in some of these classes.

To make it easier for anyone who is willing to help (thank you!) [here](https://gist.github.com/synchronizing/a0b7e1dd9514893cf2f3205f4b936772) is the gist with the entire code. For StackOverflow purposes, here is what I have:

### Setup

- `Obj`: An object that requires some asynchronous processing to be done before being accessed.

```py
class Obj(object):
    async def process(self):
        print("Processing our obj {}.".format(id(self)))
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
        self.items = random.sample(range(1000), 1000)
```

- `Pool`: A class that manages the integration of `asyncio.Queue` object.

```py
class Pool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = asyncio.LifoQueue(maxsize=10)

    async def put(self, number):
        if self.queue.full():
            print("Queue is currently full.")

        await self.queue.put(number)

    async def get(self):
        # REFERENCE POINT #1.1
        return await self.queue.get()

   async def report_on_number(self, number, good):
        # REFERENCE POINT #1.2
        print("Number {} has been reported.")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 101))

        if good:
            await self.put(number)
```

- `Filter`: A class for filtering the object.

```py
class Filter(object):
    async def filter(self, number):
        print("Filtering our number {}.".format(number))
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 101))
        return True
```

- `Main`: The main logic of the program.

```py
class Main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.objects = [Obj() for objects in range(3)]
        self.pool = Pool()
        self.filter = Filter()

    async def setup(self):
        async def pipeline(object):
            await object.process()
            await asyncio.wait([process(number) for number in object.items])

        async def process(number):
            # REFERENCE POINT #2
            if await self.filter.filter(number):
                print("Number {} was filtered.".format(number))
                await self.pool.put(number)

        await asyncio.wait([pipeline(object) for object in self.objects])
```

- Running code.

```py
asyncio.run(Main().setup())
```

---

### Question

I am trying to accomplish two things, and I believe both can be solved with the integration of one or more (well placed) asyncio primitives -- how, I am unsure.

1.) `# REFERENCE POINT #1.1 & #1.2`: When a user pulls from the `Pool` class he/she has the ability to re-insert the number back into the queue if it served its purposes during the user's task. If the number did not serve its purpose correctly, the user will report the number and the number will not be added back into the queue. This is done by some sort of `report_on_number` functionality.

2.) `# REFERENCE POINT #2`: Here, this is more of the design flaw that I am unsure how to properly figure out. Specifically, the issue is that I would only like `self.filter.filter(number)` to be called when there is a new spot in the `Pool.queue` object to save resource in the `asyncio.loop` (this is the `await queue.is_no_longer_full()` "magic" method I was talking about earlier). With the current implementation, *all* of the numbers get filtered, and then the ones that weren't inserted into the pool stagnate in the `Pool.put` functionality. This is not something I actually want.

---

### Attempts at Fixing

Before coming here I tried several different methods to solving this. The more bootlegged one is simply by adding a `while` loop inside `Main.process`:

```
async def process(number):
    while self.filter.queue.full():
        asyncio.sleep(100)

    if await self.filter.filter(number):
        print("Number {} was filtered.".format(number))
        await self.pool.put(number)
```

Which is of course just bad practice altogether. This seems to work up to a standard, but it doesn't guarantee the level of "*finess*" I am frankly looking for.

The second attempt was by using an `asyncio.Condition()` that is initialized inside the `Main` class, and passed unto the `Pool` and `Filter` class on initialization. This, however, I have been unable to implement successfully due to what I am thinking is simply lack of comfortless with core asyncio primitives. I tried several different implementations, with no success -- usually, things get locked out, and I haven't been able to contemplate an efficient way to ensure things get unlocked appropriately.

Hopefully I got my point across, and hopefully, someone is willing to help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my own problem after working through the problem with the demo that I wrote for this question. In case someone is looking for this, this is eventually what I came up with:

```py
class Pool(object):
    def __init__(self, condition):
        self.condition = condition
        self.queue = asyncio.LifoQueue(maxsize=10)

    async def put(self, number):
        if self.queue.full():
            print("-> Queue is currently full.")

            async with self.condition:
                await self.condition.wait()

        print("Adding {} to queue.".format(number))
        await self.queue.put(number)

    async def get(self):
        return await self.queue.get()

    async def report_on_number(self, number, good):
        print("   -> Number {} has been reported.".format(number))
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(2, 4))
        if good:
            print("   -> Adding number {} back into the queue.".format(number))
            await self.queue.put(number)
            print("   -> Added successfully!")
        else:
            print("   -> Releasing lock.")
            self.condition.release()
            print("   -> Lock released completed.")
```

```
class Main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.objects = [Obj() for objects in range(3)]
        self.condition = asyncio.Condition()
        self.pool = Pool(self.condition)
        self.filter = Filter()

    async def setup(self):
        async def pipeline(object):
            await object.process()
            await asyncio.wait([process(number) for number in object.items])

        async def process(number):
            async with self.condition:
                print("Processing number ", number)
                if await self.filter.filter(number):
                    await self.pool.put(number)

        await asyncio.wait([pipeline(object) for object in self.objects])
```

```py
async def test(main):

    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    print("\n\n-------- First run ---------- \n\n")
    print("\n -> Getting some number.")
    number = await main.pool.get()
    print(" -> Got number", number)
    await main.pool.report_on_number(number, False)

    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("\n\n-------- Second run ---------- \n\n")
    print("\n -> Getting some number.")
    number = await main.pool.get()
    print(" -> Got number", number)
    await main.pool.report_on_number(number, True)

    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("\n\n-------- Third run ---------- \n\n")
    print("\n -> Getting some number.")
    number = await main.pool.get()
    print(" -> Got number", number)
    await main.pool.report_on_number(number, False)

main = Main()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(main.setup())
loop.create_task(test(main))
loop.run_forever()
```

Which outputs:

```
... A bunch of processing/filtering printouts above.
...

Processing number  864
Filtering our number 864.
-> Queue is currently full.

-------- First run ---------- 

 -> Getting some number.
 -> Got number 34
   -> Number 34 has been reported.
   -> Releasing lock.
   -> Lock released completed.
Processing number  866
Filtering our number 866.
Adding 866 to queue.
Processing number  121
Filtering our number 121.
-> Queue is currently full.

-------- Second run ---------- 

 -> Getting some number.
 -> Got number 866
   -> Number 866 has been reported.
   -> Adding number 866 back into the queue.
   -> Added successfully!

-------- Third run ---------- 

 -> Getting some number.
 -> Got number 866
   -> Number 866 has been reported.
   -> Releasing lock.
   -> Lock released completed.
Processing number  55
Filtering our number 55.
Adding 55 to queue.
Processing number  19
Filtering our number 19.
-> Queue is currently full.
```

It's working solid!

Comment: Using a condition variable is the right thing.

You can even replace `asyncio.LifoQueue` with a custom queue class using a list, mutex, and two condition variables. Take a look at `./Lib/queue.py` for inspiration (asyncio queue is implemented differently for historical reasons).

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov I'm not certain why I never got back to you here, but thank you for the reply. I'm going to check out the class you specified, and see if I can make something out of it -- the question posted here is for a project that I've had to put in pause, but working on it now. I appreciate the tip!